# Blurry google material icons

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-drawable

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm currently developing an Android app using Android studio. I needed some icons and so I decided to download them from the Google material icons.

**Now my problem is that these icons appear blurry in my app**. I know that I need to have many folders for specific dimensions, and that's what I did from the beginning, but I still have this problem.

I have also tried to use other images from another application that I have developed and those were perfectly ok. **So the problem seems to be related to the material icons**.

Here is the steps that I have done precisely :

1) Download the google material icons for the headset icon.

2) unzip the file

3) copy the drawable folders from the android section inside my android studio.

4) execute the app

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The better option instead of using drawables/bitmaps for the icons is using vectors.

Here is a bit of documentation on using vectors in Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#VectorDrawables

Using vectors instead of bitmaps will help with the resolution issue you seem to be having.